# PreRendering does not persist variable values used to trap second pass

Tags: blazor, pre-rendering

I have reviewed the various articles on how Blazor Server Apps are prerendered then rendered in two passes.  I have reviewed the LifeCycle and am very clear that this is expected behavior largely intended to provide good performance.  I do not want to turn off the prerendering, so I have to account for it when loading data structures and similar things.

I need to be able to run my code that interacts with the database once.  I have looked at a variety of the events that are supposed to help with this yet none seem to work.

One of the primary issues I am seeing is that any Boolean variable I use to record the first pass is not persisting the value during the second pass so I cannot use that to avoid doing the work twice.

In other words, in my experience, the second pass behaves as if the first pass never happened, so nothing set in the first pass is available during the second pass.

This is making it impossible to manage the double rendering.

If I do this, I end up with a Development Error page:

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bink");
        //await OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        await Initialize();
    }
}
```

If I do this, the isInitialized variable is never set to true when inspected in the If statement.  It is always false, so it seems like each pass is completely independent of the previous pass, which is not how I understood it to work.:

```
 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if(isInitialized)
    {
        return;
    }
    isInitialized = true;
    await Initialize();
    //await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
```

How can I implement a solution that will only run my Initialization code once while preserving the two pass rendering?  I see a lot of solutions that are supposed to work yet none do, so how do I resolve this?

Comment: The usual way is the wait for `OnAfterRenderAsync` to be called, test `firstRender` and when it is true, `await SomeMethod()`, which can call `StateHasChanged` to re-render when it has finished fetching data; but `SomeMethod` should NOT be one of the standard lifetime methods of a Component. `firstRender` will only be true once in the lifetime of a component - and the component will be interactive at this point. *Your code example called `Initialize` - which I presume is your code - but it did it after every render*

Comment: I ran across that pattern, and it did not work for me.  None of the methods that allegedly run the second time did anything for me, I had to use the pattern shown below that truly gave me access to the value from the first pass.  As noted, the problem is that each pass is its own isolated context, and that prevented the flags from persisting between rendering passes.

Luckily I am all set now, the solution provided below was exactly what I needed.

Thanks for the input, much appreciated!

Comment: If you ever want to get to the bottom of why you couldn't get that to work, a small repro would be useful. You really shouldn't need to inject anything to handle prerendering and accessing the database at the correct time.

Comment: Having tested repeatedly, I have spent as much time as I can on this.  As noted in the answer below the contexts is indeed different, which is why my variables did not persist. As to why the prerender and render methods did not work, honestly, I have no idea and definitely do not have the time to debug MS code.  Whatever is going on will have to be fixed by someone with the time to dig in, characterize the issue and report it.  I am way behind on this project due to so many issues like this that I do not have the bandwidth to do any more.

Comment: I understand, but be clear that this is not a bug - MS have nothing to fix - it is your understanding that is missing - so you really should open up some time to resolve what you were doing wrong, or you will likely do it again in future.

Comment: @Mister Magoo: I read the documentation and it clearly states that there are two passes, but it strongly implies they share a context.  So what is going on here, then?  I am OK with my understanding being the issue, but whatever is going on here has to make sense, and ar this time I do not see how the Prerendering is as described in the Docs as I kept having failures that were contrary to what was stated in the docs.  That is partly why it was so hard to debug.

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "share a context" and what documentation you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second loads are run in two different contexts.  The only thing they share are singleton services.

You can detect the load using the `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Add the service in `Program`:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In any page or component you can then do this:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private bool _isServerRender;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => _isServerRender = !(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted);

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (_isServerRender)
        {
            // Do minumum to dispay page
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }

        // Do normal stuff
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Where you use this code depends on what you want to achieve.  You can run it in `Index`, or you can run it in `App` and just display a loading screen.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I implemented your solution, did a slight reorganization of the HTML so it only tries to build any tables when the data is available, and it is working wonderfully now.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Use of IHttpContextAccessor is highly discouraged by MS. In some circumstances, it may be null (in production environment).

Comment: Yes, when there's other ways to access the HttpContext.  Only use it as the last resort. Note the following MS document - see section **Access HttpContext from custom components**. https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/http-context.md.   Do you have a better way of detecting pre-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to allow the pre-render to run the full initialization code during OnIntialized() and then use the persist the pre-rendered state using the PersistentComponentState that is described in the following link.

[Prerender ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

In this way, the second load will utilise the data generated in the first load.

The choice of which way to go probably depends on your app.  I use it for role-based authentication where I want to get the state so that I show the correct screen to the user as early as possible, but I don't want another round-trip to the server on the second render.

Alternatively, if you have a large amount of data to load into a grid, you might want to hold off and load it after pre-render as per the other answer by @MrC aka Shaun Curtis.

It can take a little while to get your head around how to use this, but it is worth spending the time to understand it and determine if it works for your situation.