# How To prevent developer code in OnInitializedAsync from running twice when prerendering

Tags: blazor

In blazor server,
I am using ServerPrerendered ,So OnInitializedAsync will execute twice, which I can understand。
The official provided a MemoryCache method to avoid executing twice.
I want to ask, is this prevention necessary? But if we don't prevent it, we will execute the development logic twice. Is there a more elegant method? thank you!

For example, my code is

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ListNewCode = await GetList();
    }

private Task<List<PostInfo>?> GetListNewCode()
    {
        string key = "Index_GetListNewCode";

        return MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(key, async e =>
       {
           e.SetOptions(new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
               {
                   AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
               });

           using var _context = await DbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

           ///other

           return list;

       });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, see this answer on detecting first and second loads using the `IHttpContextAccessor` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778169/13065781

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I want. I love you!

Comment: Now, looking at it, this is not a good method. It's better to change ServerPrendered to Server using this method