# What is the best way in Blazor to initialize a page that hits the DB to initialize itself

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

[What I learned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76451978/oninitializedasync-is-being-called-twice) is I want to set `render-mode="Server"` in _Host.cshtml. This way the page is rendered once.

But... this is also the slowest way to render the page. If the code in my `OnInitializedAsync()` is hitting the DB, then nothing will be rendered until I've read everything from the DB.

For this case, is it better to read in that data in `OnAfterRenderAsync(true)`? In this case the page will be rendered with no data, and then the data will fill.

And, for my case at least, and variables that impact layout in terms of what's visible, what's enabled, etc. I can set in `OnInitializedAsync()` without hitting the DB. So tables/grids will grow once I populate the data, but other than that, it would just be fields being populated with their initial data.

So what is normally done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double render only occurs on the landing page, so you can either:

1. Keep the page light on activity.
2. Detect the double render and don't do any DB work in the first render.

There's an answer here that shows how to detect the first render using the `IHttpContextAccessor` service and use it to modify the component behaviour.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778169/13065781

Here's a demo page showing how to handle what you've described within the normal component lifecycle.

Note that, as I've pointed out before, good design = no need to resort to the `OnAfterRenderAsync` kludge.  Personal: My components don't implement `IHandleAfterRender`, if I need it for JSInterop I implement it on a component by component basis.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@if (_isServerRender)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">Pre-Loading</div>
}
else if(_loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Loading</div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        Welcome to your new app.

        < SurveyPrompt Title = "How is Blazor working for you?" />
    </div>
}


@code {
    public Guid Uid { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    private bool _loading;
    private bool _isServerRender;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => _isServerRender = !(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted);

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        if (_isServerRender)
            return;

        // emulate a lot of DB async activity
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the answer but is it official that OnInitialized() will be called before OnInitializedAsync() ? I know it is now, but is that a spec?

Comment: @HH I believe I read somewhere (and memory is faulty) that the sync call always occurs before the async call - for every pair of calls in Blazor.

Comment: Why not use `OnAfterRenderAsync ()`? It seems to me that this sort of defines what I want - fast render of the page and then, we got a quick display of the page to the user, now read the DB and populate it. And have a `loading ...` over the page until it all completes. Clearly you don't like this approach - can you explain why? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen - I don't like it because in general it's pointless, you are doing more renders and render cascades that you need to.  Slower application and more CPU cycles to pay for.  Please put a [MRE] of what you're code would look like in another question and hopefully I'll show you why [I want to use someone else's code rather than invent my own MRE].

Comment: @HH - I don't think it's policy, but ComponentBase is such a fundamental part of most people's UI, If MS were to change the order, I think we would hear the community howls on the moon! You can move the code to the first line of the async method it you want to be sure

Comment: Yes, I'm quitre sure it won't break. But it just feels wrong to use both. As does the requirement to _know_ the sequence.  I would indeed use the HttpContextAccessor in the start of the Async method.

Comment: I created a [MRE here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2zritrfx7zzh2c/InitializeSample.zip?dl=1) figuring I could show you the difference. And... you are right. No difference. But it was worth the effort because it made one thing very clear to me - initialize everything you can before hitting the DB in `OnInitializedAsync()`. That way you get everything you can rendered properly. So once again, thank you

Comment: No problem, you learned a valuable lesson. If you need to call StateHasChanged in OnAfterRender then it's likely to be very smelly code!

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 will bring a new feature to Blazor server called `Streaming Rendering`. This will allow a page to render while the data is loading.

For more information take a look on this [blog post from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-4/#blazor).

All you'll need to do basically is to provide an attribute `@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]`

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorSSR.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

@if (forecasts is null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    // Render weather forecasts
}

@code {
    private string message;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```