# Blazor javascript interop error when accessing localstorage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am unable to avoid getting this error, whatever i try with my arhitecture and i'm lost on how this should be fixed.

Error: `JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.`

This happens when any api is called from frontend and i'm trying to read a key from localstorage to obtain a jwt token to attach in the http header.

For example:

```
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
             LoadDataAsync();
             StateHasChanged();
            _loaded = true;
        }

        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        var data = await DashboardClient.GetAsync();
        if (data is StatsDto statsDto)
        {
            CustomersCount = statsDto.CustomersCount;

            UserCount = statsDto.UserCount;
            RoleCount = statsDto.RoleCount;
            foreach (var item in statsDto.DataEnterBarChart)
            {
                _dataEnterBarChartSeries
                    .RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Equals(item.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                _dataEnterBarChartSeries.Add(new MudBlazor.ChartSeries { Name = item.Name, Data = item.Data?.ToArray() });
            }
        }
    }
```

This call will get intercepted here:

```
using ContractManagementUI.Client.Infrastructure.Storage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ContractManagementUI.Client.Infrastructure.Auth.Jwt;

public class JwtAuthenticationHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigation;
    private readonly IDistributedCacheStorageService _distributedCacheStorageService;
    private readonly ProtectedLocalStorage _localStorage;

    public JwtAuthenticationHeaderHandler(
        NavigationManager navigation,
        ProtectedLocalStorage localStorageService,
        IDistributedCacheStorageService distributedCacheStorageService)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
        _localStorage = localStorageService;
        _distributedCacheStorageService = distributedCacheStorageService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // skip token endpoints
        if (request.RequestUri?.AbsolutePath.Contains("/tokens") is not true)
        {
            ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string?> protectedStorageValue = await _localStorage.GetAsync<string>(StorageConstants.Local.UserId);

            var userId = protectedStorageValue.Value;

            if(userId is not null)
            {
                _distributedCacheStorageService.UserId = userId;

                var token = await _distributedCacheStorageService.ReadCachedValue(StorageConstants.Local.AuthToken);
                if (token is not null)
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                }
                else
                {
                    _navigation.NavigateTo("login");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _navigation.NavigateTo("login");
            }
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And it will fail instalty when it tries to run the line
`await _localStorage.GetAsync<string>(StorageConstants.Local.UserId);`

This is how my dependency looks for auth part in case it matters:

```
 _ => services
                .AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, JwtAuthenticationService>()
                .AddScoped(sp => (IAuthenticationService)sp.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>())
                .AddScoped(sp => (IAccessTokenProvider)sp.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>())
                .AddScoped<IAccessTokenProviderAccessor, AccessTokenProviderAccessor>()
                .AddScoped<JwtAuthenticationHeaderHandler>()
```

I am complety out of ideeas on what to try next, I tried to rethink where the localstorage read is and it does not matter as long as this code gets hit it will throw javascript interop error.

Comment: See this link for how to detect the pre-render.  You should be able to use the technique to run the code in the second render.https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778169/13065781

Comment: @RuikaiFeng i'm using .net7

Comment: Not yet, i commented it everywhere to isolate the issue. This only happens if i try to read from local storage inside  override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same situation, and I changed the way the component is being render in the `_Host.cshtml` file.

I changed from this

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

To

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
```